# SwiftUi I can not delete item

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can't understand why the error occurs. The `addItem()` works, but an error occurs when `removeItem()` is executed.

**MyViewModel**

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items:[MyModel] = []
}
```

---

**MyModel**

```
struct MyModel : Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title:String
    var value:String
}
```

---

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {

@StateObject var model = MyViewModel()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            addItem()
        }) {
            Text("add")
        }
        ForEach(0..<model.items.count, id: \.self) { index in
            HStack {
            TextField("value", text: Binding(get: { self.model.items[index].value },
                                        set: { self.model.items[index].value = $0 }))
                Button(action: {
                    removeItem()
                }) {
                    Text("delete")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
func addItem() {
    self.model.items.append(MyModel(id: +1, title: "", value: ""))
}
func removeItem() {
    if let index = model.items.first?.id {
        model.items.remove(at: index)
    }
}
}
```

I think the problem is in `func removeItem()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `ForEach`

As mention in the apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:content:)-6db7u)

> `ForEach` : The instance only reads the initial value of the provided data and doesn’t need to identify views across updates.

So when you remove an object from the array, you have changed the array but SwiftUI doesn't see that change and it uses the original array.

So, you just fix it by just adding conditions like this `index < self.model.items.count ? self.model.items[index].value : ""`

Also, I suggest using `.indices` in `ForEach`

One more point you no need to find index every time on delete. Just pass the index to function.

Here is the complete code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = MyViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                addItem()
            }) {
                Text("add")
            }
            ForEach(model.items.indices, id:\.self) { index in //< -- Here
                HStack {
                    TextField("value", text: Binding(get: {  index < self.model.items.count ? self.model.items[index].value : "" }, //<-- Here
                                                     set: { self.model.items[index].value = $0 }))
                    Button(action: {
                        removeItem(at: index) //< -- Here
                    }) {
                        Text("delete")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func addItem() {
        self.model.items.append(MyModel(title: "", value: ""))
    }
    
    func removeItem(at index: Int) {
        model.items.remove(at: index) //< -- Here
    }
}
```

Comment: can you make an example without using the binding ? like with a subview or something or direct items such as a normal text and image etc.. or within a vstack ?