# Delete image in ForEach cycle

Tags: swift, swiftui, phasset

I have array with selected images from media library. And I need to delete selected image by clicking on button.

```
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    HStack(spacing: 5) {
        ForEach(self.selectedMedia, id:\.self) { index in
            ZStack {
                Image(uiImage: index.image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.5)
                Button(action: {
                    removeItem(at: index)
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                        .padding(5)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        .background(Color.white)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

func removeItem(at index: Int) {
    self.selectedMedia.remove(at: index)
}
```

But can't build project, because have an error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'SelectedMedia' to expected argument type 'Int'
```

`SelectedMedia`:

```
struct SelectedMedia: Hashable {
    var asset: PHAsset
    var image: UIImage
}
```

If I print current element in array `print(index)`, will get in console:

```
SelectedMedia(asset: <PHAsset: 0x149313570> ED7AC36B-A150-4C38-BB8C-B6D696F4F2ED/L0/001 mediaType=1/0, sourceType=1, (3000x2002), creationDate=2012-08-08 21:55:30 +0000, location=1, hidden=0, favorite=0, adjusted=0 , image: <UIImage:0x6000004c4360 anonymous {3000, 2002}>)
```

How to fix error and delete image?

Comment: this method required int value ```.remove(at:``` and you are passing SelectedMedia object ```i``` which is wrong. you have to pass index of item

Comment: See example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68509759/14733292

Comment: @RajaKishan yes, I need `INT` value. But how I can get it in my cycle?

Comment: check my given example ```ForEach(model.items.indices, id:\.self) { index in //< -- Here
```

Comment: Yes, I am reading this article now... Thanks.

Comment: I have update my code and have the same error. Please, check my question. I have update it.

Comment: You have to change ```ForEach``` loop definition

Comment: I don't understand how to do it)) Before that it was `ForEach(self.selectedMedia, id: \.self) { i in`, now I replaced this to `ForEach(self.selectedMedia, id: \.self) { index in` as in your example. How I need to define the loop? It is already defined...

Comment: you missed ```selectedMedia.indices``` part see my answere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can use this.

Approach 1: Use `indices` and then get an object from the index.

```
ForEach(selectedMedia.indices, id:\.self) { index in // <-- Here
    let obj = selectedMedia[index] // <-- Here
    ZStack {
        Image(uiImage: obj.image) // <-- Here
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.5)
        Button(action: {
            removeItem(at: index) // <-- Here
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "trash")
                .padding(5)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .background(Color.white)
        })
    }
}
```

Approach 2: Use `enumerated()` it will give you both item object and offset.

```
ForEach(Array(selectedMedia.enumerated()), id:\.offset) { index, obj in // <-- Here
    ZStack {
        Image(uiImage: obj.image) // <-- Here
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.5)
        Button(action: {
            removeItem(at: index) // <-- Here
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "trash")
                .padding(5)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .background(Color.white)
        })
    }
}
```

Approach 3: Find index from the array by object

```
struct SelectedMedia: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var asset: PHAsset
    var image: UIImage
}
```

```
ForEach(self.selectedMedia, id:\.id) { object in // <-- Here
    ZStack {
        Image(uiImage: object.image) // <-- Here
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.5)
        Button(action: {
            if let index = self.selectedMedia.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == object.id}) { // <-- Here
                removeItem(at: index) // <-- Here
            }
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "trash")
                .padding(5)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .background(Color.white)
        })
    }
}
```