# how to delete an item in a forEach loop with a delete btn for each of it. I use swiftUI with core data

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

Here is the code if you don't understand

```
struct cartView: View {
        @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
        @FetchRequest(
            sortDescriptors: [], animation: .default) private var products: FetchedResults<Prod>
        
        let columns = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]
        @State var indx = 0
    
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                            ForEach(products, id: \.self) {prod in
                                let prodItems = Product(name: prod.name ?? "Undefined", price: prod.price ?? "Undefined", type: "type", brand: prod.brand ?? "Undefined", images: [prod.image!,""])
                                
                                    ZStack {
                                    Cells(product: prodItems)
                                    // I want the button below delete the item of the 
                                    // button pressed with the function below
                                    Button(action: {}) {
                                        Image(systemName: "xmark.bin.circle")
                                            .resizable()
                                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                                            .background(.black)
                                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                                            .offset(x: 60, y: 45)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Cart")
            }
        }
        
        private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
            withAnimation {
                offsets.map { products[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
    
                do {
                    try viewContext.save()
                } catch {
                    let nsError = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
                }
            }
        }
}
```

so the question here is the button there in the forEach loop to delete the item that the user pressed the button and I know how to do it, but what I don't know is how to get the index of the item and pass it in the function.

Comment: Does this your answere? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68509759/14733292
This one also helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68587880/14733292

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete Core Data SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68432307/how-to-delete-core-data-swiftui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need the index if you're issuing the delete instruction from within your loop, as your `NSManagedObjectContext` instance has a `delete(_:)` method that takes the object itself. That change will propagate through your `@FetchRequest` object automatically, your SwiftUI view will update to show the collection without the now-deleted object.

So your button action becomes:

```swift
Button(action: {
  viewContext.delete(prod)
}) {
  Image(systemName: ...)
  // etc.
}
```

Note that while you'll see the effect straight away, the deletion will only be in memory until you call `save` on the managed object context.

In my CoreData apps, I tend to save my changes separately, for example when the app is about to go into the background. But if you want to trigger a save immediately the object is removed, that's straightforward enough:

```swift
Button(action: {
  viewContext.delete(prod)
  try? viewContext.save()
}) {
  Image(systemName: ...)
  // etc.
}
```

*NB: the documentation for `NSManagedObjectContext.save()` says that you should check the `hasChanges` property before attempting to save, but as you've just made a change in the line above, that's not necessary in this particular example.*

Comment: thanks a lot, It works, u really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Deleting Core Data items with SwiftUI (especially in a ForEach loop with NavigationLinks) often ends in an app crash. This can be fixed on IOS using a special modifier, (which I will look up) but it is not working at all on MacOS at this point (apparently it is a "system bug"), and dismissing the view is nearly impossible, it seems (I have tried many solutions-- many will work for IOS but not on Mac apps).
The only workaround I have found is to use the .isFault operation on the entity, and return an empty view. Not pretty but it works:
Deleting Core Data items with SwiftUI (especially in a ForEach loop with NavigationLinks) often ends in an app crash. This can be fixed on IOS using a special modifier, (which I will look up) but it is not working at all on MacOS at this point (apparently it is a "system bug"), and dismissing the view is nearly impossible, it seems (I have tried many solutions-- many will work for IOS but not on Mac apps).

The only workaround I have found is to use the .isFault operation on the entity, and return an empty view. Not pretty but it works:

```
    if entity.isFault {
    EmptyView()
}
else {
    // your regular view body
}
```